# How to force date fomat in Angular 8 with an html DatePicker?

Tags: angular, datepicker, format

I'm using the default Angular 8 datepicker, and currently it is taking the format from the browser's language (English (US) is MM/DD/YYYY), and I'd like to force it to DD/MM/YYY.

How can I do this?

Here's my input with datepicker:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" max="2070-12-31" name="arrivalDate" id="arrivalDate" required>
```

Comment: That is not an Angular datepicker, but just the default html type datepicker based on your browser's implementation.

Comment: Ok, so the question remains: how can I change the format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: If you are using web components such as ones provided by Angular Material, you can also integrate them with `Moment.js` which would allow you to handle different formats and locales efficiently.